# Dynamically populate work week number in excel

Tags: excel

I have a requirement to generate column headers based on file name in excel.
for eg: If file name is ABC_WW201702.xlsx - this means this file contains data for 2nd work week of 2017. Every week a new file will be created.

In excel, I need my column headers to dynamically populate the next 52 work weeks inclusive of the current. For eg :

```
Ww02 WW03...WW51 WW01
```

I tried to use the following formula to extract the last few characters of the file name :

```
=(LEFT(RIGHT(MID(CELL("filename",A1),FIND("[",CELL("filename",A1))+1,FIND("]",CELL("filename",A1))-FIND("[",CELL("filename",A1))-1),11),6))
```

and further split the values into Year and Work week using LEFT/RIGHT function. However Im unable to dynamically populate for next 52 work weeks.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try something like this

In A1

```
="WW"&RIGHT(REPLACE(CELL("filename",A1),FIND(".",CELL("filename",A1)),255,""),2)+COLUMNS($A:A)-1
```

and then copy it across.

**Edit:**

Actually you will need two formulas. One formula in A1 and another in B1 which is copied across to give you the desired output.

In A1

```
="WW"&TEXT(RIGHT(REPLACE(CELL("filename",A1),FIND(".",CELL("filename",A1)),255,""),2)+MOD(COLUMNS($A1:A1),52)-1,"00")
```

In B1

```
="WW"&TEXT(IF(RIGHT(A1,2)*1<52,RIGHT(A1,2)+1,1),"00")
```

and copy it across.

Comment: This works to some extent. However after WW52 I want the next column header to be WW01 instead of WW54 as it rolls into the first work week for next year. I shall try to tweak your code to achieve this

Comment: It did not work. It still populated as WW54 WW55.Can you review your formula once more

Comment: This worked perfectly for me. We may have issues when there are 53 weeks in a year and well that's in 2019 and this implementation is for a short term. A big thank you for the solution you gave me. Very much appreciated :)

Comment: You're welcome Mekha! Glad I could help. Please take a moment to accept the answer and mark your question as Solved.